# Add code in compilation phase

Tags: c#, roslyn, afterthought

I would like to just have a simple

```
[LogData]
public class MyFancyClass
{

  public void DoStuff(int x){}

}
```

I would like to get the class parameter name along with their values, so check if x was 5 ot r 5.

Can this be done with roslyn or do i need afterthought.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the question. You might wish to clarify it a bit.

Comment: Roslyn cannot do that.

Comment: There's a NuGet package called `StackExchange.Precompilation` that allows pre-compilation syntax rewriting using the Roslyn API.  You can use it to inject code into Roslyn's syntax tress before any IL is emitted.  This can be applied to logging, method input checks, etc.  I've started working on design-by-contract using this https://github.com/JamesFaix/Traction